# PROCEDIMIENTO ALMACENADO postgres

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql, stored-procedure

mi duda es la siguiente.
Tengo el siguiente procedimiento almacenado, que tiene como finalidad realizar la misma función pero para tres esquemas diferentes (dentro de una misma base de datos). Mi código es el siguiente:

```
FOR i IN 1..4
loop
cod = 0;
esquemaTabla = '';

if i=1 AND muni = 'municipalidad' THEN 
    cod=1; 
    esquemaTabla := 'municipalidad'; 
end if;

if i=2 AND edu = 'educacion' THEN 
    cod=2; 
    esquemaTabla := 'educacion'; 
end if;

if i=3 AND salud = 'salud' THEN 
    cod=3; 
    esquemaTabla := 'salud'; 
end if;

if i=4 AND cementer = 'cementerio' THEN 
    cod=4; 
    esquemaTabla := 'cementerio'; 
end if;

insert into esquemaTable.tabla....

END loop;
```

El problema es el siguiente, **al ingresar la variable esquemaTable** postgres me lo tomo como el nombre del esquema "esquemaTable" y no por su valor que sería "municipalidad", "educacion" o "salud".

Answer (score 1):

Ese seria el comportamiento esperado..., por lo que entiendo necesitas un valor dinámico en esquemaTabla , por ende debes ejecutar esa consulta de insert into dinamicamente con un [execute](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) y quedaria mas menos asi:

```
FOR i IN 1..4
loop
cod = 0;
esquemaTabla = '';

if i=1 AND muni = 'municipalidad' THEN 
cod=1; 
esquemaTabla := 'municipalidad'; 
end if;

if i=2 AND edu = 'educacion' THEN 
cod=2; 
esquemaTabla := 'educacion'; 
end if;

if i=3 AND salud = 'salud' THEN 
cod=3; 
esquemaTabla := 'salud'; 
end if;

if i=4 AND cementer = 'cementerio' THEN 
cod=4; 
esquemaTabla := 'cementerio'; 
end if;

EXECUTE format('insert into  %I.tabla...',esquemaTable) ;

END loop;
```

O de lo contrario haz el insert into dentro de cada if y te quitas el tema de la ejecucion dinamica si te complica mucho

```
FOR i IN 1..4
loop
cod = 0;
esquemaTabla = '';

if i=1 AND muni = 'municipalidad' THEN 
cod=1; 
insert into municipalidad.tabla....;

end if;

if i=2 AND edu = 'educacion' THEN 
cod=2; 
insert into educacion.tabla....;
end if;

if i=3 AND salud = 'salud' THEN 
cod=3; 
insert into municipalidad.tabla....;
end if;

if i=4 AND cementer = 'cementerio' THEN 
cod=4; 
insert into cementerio.tabla....; 
end if;


END loop;
```